# Table design will not update in azure through SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure-web-app-service

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v17.5 to update a column header. Someone had misspelled a column header. I corrected every misspelling in the backend code. I followed the instructions at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/design-tables-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-2017

However, on my website, I'm getting errors from my api telling me that it can't find the correct column header in the database and that it is still spelled the old incorrect way. Is there something else I have to do to get this column header to update? It is spelled correctly in my SQL Server Management Studio.

I cannot reproduce this bug locally. Everything works fine.

The SQL Server database and website are hosted in Azure. The website is an app service.

Comment: Sounds silly, but maybe you didn't deploy the code with your fix to the correct machine?

Comment: I can see the changes in my git repo and I can see that that specific branch was deployed through appveyor.

Comment: What happens when you query your table column from SSMS?

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: Renaming a column is supported by Azure SQL Databases and this seems to be some weird cache... does not make sense. Try scaling up and down the database to try refresh it... finally just try to recreate your table

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to check:

1.Make sure the updated code has been pushed to azure.

2.Go to azure portal -> SQL database -> your own database, then click the `Query editor` and login the db, to check if the `column header` is modified or not:
[image]

The issue is not reproduced at my side, it works ok both on local and azure.

Comment: Your first point was the solution. We deploy through appveyor. I did not realize that the specific service throwing the error was the only one that has to be manually deployed via appveyor.